# Dynamic URL in Laravel 5.0

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display a specific link on all the pages in my web application. The link is given below

`<a href="my-link">Some text for the link!</a>`

My routes file

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('path1/path2/path3', 'SomeController@someFunction');
Route::get('my-link', 'SomeController@myLink');
```

While browsing the web application, when I am at `mydoamin.com/home`, the link address is `mydomain.com/my-link`, which is correct.

But when I am at the URL `mydoamin.com/path1/path2/path3`, the link address becomes `mydoamin.com/path1/path2/my-link`. Hence, after clicking the link I get 404 error as the path doesn't exist.

How do I make the link to always show `mydomain.com/my-link` on all the pages without hard-coding the domain name?

*Note: I have put the link code `<a href="my-link">Some text for the link!</a>` in a partial file; and I am including that file in all the pages.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why you shouldn't use `/my-link`?**

You could use `<a href="/my-link">My link</a>` on a site that's running on the root directory (`www.domain.com/my-link`). But if you're running it in a subdirectory you need to change all the url's.

That's why Laravel introduced `named routes`, this will automatically creates the correct url.

For example:

If you're site runs at `www.domain.com/my-website/` and you need to point to `/my-link` you need to change all your links in your project to `/my-website/...`.

So I suggest to use `named routes`.

---

How to use `named routes`

> Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes.

And this is de code you need to use:

```
Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('path1/path2/path3', ['as' => 'path3', 'uses' => 'SomeController@someFunction']);
Route::get('my-link', ['as' => 'my-link', 'uses' => 'SomeController@myLink']);
```

After that you can use:

```
<a href="{{ url(route('my-link')) }}">
    Some text for the link!
</a>
```

Laravel will automatically create the correct url for the named route you want to use.

Hope this works!

More information at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: I agree with you. Your solution is better.

Comment: Thank you @linuxartisan ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be `href="/my-link"`, `/` means start from root.

You may try different ways like `./my-link` ,`../my-link` or `../../my-link` to see what happend.

see [link: absolute, relative, root](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php)